# How to get specific values from a dictionary using list comprehension and modify them?

Tags: list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Can someone help and kindly advise how Can I get specific values from this dictionary (Using list comprehension) and

1. square the values only,
2. change every string value, so it starts with upper case?

```
items_list = {'a': 3, 'b':6, 'c': 'short', 'h': 'example', 'p': 77}
```

So, the output needs to be:

```
9, 36, 5929
Short, Example
```

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Are there just strings and integers in values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Python):

```py
items_list = {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 'short', 'h': 'example', 'p': 77}

lst = [v ** 2 if isinstance(v, (int, float)) else v.capitalize() for v in
       items_list.values()]

print(lst)
```

output:

```
[9, 36, 'Short', 'Example', 5929]
```

The exact output that you showed can not be produced using single list comprehension, because the iteration is in order.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to iterate through the dictionary and check if the value is an int then square it and if it is not capitalize it

```
result = []
for key, value in dictionary.items()
    if type(value) is int:
        result.append(value**2)
    else:
        result.append(value.capitalize())
print(result)
```

this should print the desired output

Comment: Do we have capitalize function in Python ? :d

Comment: Yes it will only put the first character in capital

Comment: I know. but it's a string method. You should call it like `value.capitalize()`

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you!